# MultiDatesPicker Days Count

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've got this working:

```
<ul class="calendar">
            <li class="demo full-row">
                <div id="full-year" class="box"></div>
                    <div>
                        <div style="float:left">

        <?php       
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                var today = new Date();
                var y = today.getFullYear();
                $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
                // addDates: ['10/14/'+y, '02/19/'+y, '01/14/'+y, '11/16/'+y],
                //  numberOfMonths: [1,3],
                minDate:0,
                altField: '#input-option".$option['product_option_id']."',
                //  defaultDate: '1/1/'+y
                });
            </script>";
        ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
               function getSelectedDays(){
                     $('#input-quantity').val($("#full-year").get(0).multiDatesPicker.dates.picked.length+1);
                    }
                    $('.ui-state-default').click(function(){
                        window.alert('test');
                        getSelectedDays();
                    });
            </script>

        </div>
    <div style="float:right">
    <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
          <div class="input-group date">
            <textarea cols="11" rows="12" type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD"  id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control"/></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
          <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_qty; ?></label>
          <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />                        
                </li>

            </ul>
```

This basically works - it gives me the result and updates the input form with the number of days but only once. So the first click on a calendar day works and updates the input form. If I select more days, the function does not trigger again

If I place the #full-year - the function works but only if I click on the calendar frame and not on the dates themselves.

Sorry for the mess in code.. not doing this usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get no of the selected date by:-

**`$("#full-year").get(0).multiDatesPicker.dates.picked.length`**.

Add this function to your code:

```
function getSelectedDays(){
    $('input#id').val($("#full-year").get(0).multiDatesPicker.dates.picked.length);
}

$('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
    ...
    onSelect: function() {
            getSelectedDays();
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort Gaurav, however:

`$(".ui-datepicker-calender").click(function(){
    getSelectedDays();
});`

 does not seem to trigger the function so I changed that to:

`$(".ui-state-default").click(function(){
    getSelectedDays();
});` which triggers the function but only once, If I continue selecting dates in the calendar, the function does not trigger again.

Comment: I have updated the code. Use $("#full-year") instead of $(".ui-datepicker-calender"). It will going to work perfectly.

Comment: Nope, the $("full-year") does not trigger it

Comment: @VictorShova Can you create a jsfiddle of your code. It will be easy to debug and we can see what is the problem. Make sure you have attached '#' before full-year.

Comment: not sure what a jsfiddle is.. i'll update the code in the initial post

Comment: @VictorShova I have updated by my code, now it is working fine. I have checked it myself.

Comment: I've wanted to do that.. but somehow missed the mark :) It's on now. Thank you again :)